# How do you configure your PeopleSoft Test Environments?

Tags: peoplesoft

What are some the items you change in your test environments to make them standout from production, and how do you go about make these changes? I know you can change the PS LOGO, but what else do you change in your test environments? Colors, fonts, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the colour schemes isn't too difficult.  If you want to go down that route and need a helping hand I'll be happy to assist.

Other clients just put the environment name in the PIA Greeting.  That's easy too:
http://peoplesofttipster.com/2007/06/13/using-the-pia-welcome-message/

I've not heard of anyone changing fonts though.

kind regards

Duncan

Answer (score 0):

When you refresh a db, make sure you change tools tables that have dbname, web urls, and so on. The test db name will appear in the portal menu.

Changing the fonts would require changing all the style sheet definitions, a major headache. I guess you could go in and edit some basic style sheet attributes in app designer, PS_TEXT, et.al. and change those in a test environment. Maybe just changing a few would be enough.

Most test envs also open up security to some degree, simply because testers and developers likely need access to everything. So people's menus are going to be much larger than in production.

Answer (score 0):

This is the relatively small change we made, to replace the "Home" link in the toolbar with the name of the environment eveywhere but prod. It was also incorporated in the refresh scripts to pull in the DBNAME dyanmically.

update psmsgcatdefn set message_text = 'DBNAME', descrlong = 'Environment name home replacement' where message_set_nbr = '95' and message_nbr = '401';

Answer (score 0):

items to watch for:

- file paths - if you open files for reading, and especially writing, to communicate with external systems, then you need to make sure you are not stepping on Production toes.
- I would assume web services would also need the same re-routing so you don't "hit" live external production web services.
- emails.  workflow or other subsystems are liable to fire off emails to users or external parties. you need to make sure those emails are tester emails instead, not real addressees.